# Mysql order by timestamp (and keep event at top of results if date is within two weeks)

Tags: mysql

I am writing a query that pulls data from different tables (user activity stream)

'events.eventdate_us' below is the actual date of the event in YYYY-MM-DD - The timestamp is the time it was posted.

How do I write my query to order by timestamp but push the event to the top if the event date is within two weeks?

```
    SELECT events.user_id,
           events.eventdate_us,
           events.start_time,
           events.event_title,
           events.description,
           events.venue,
           events.add1,
           events.city,
           events.country,
           events.website,
           'NULL' AS update_msg,
           'NULL' AS buying_selling,
           'NULL' AS stock_type,
           events.timestamp AS timestamp,
                               'events' AS source,
                               users.contact_person,
                               users.company,
                               users.pic_small,
                               users.pic_large
    FROM events
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = events.user_id
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 30
```

I should add that this is part of a few UNION calls to get everything I needed in the query

below is what I am trying to achieve (event within two weeks at top) - I can get this with 
ORDER BY eventdate_us = '2014-07-31' DESC, timestamp DESC LIMIT 30 but I have to specify the exact date.

[image]

What I would like to do is get all events within two weeks, something like ORDER BY eventdate_us < NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY DESC, timestamp DESC LIMIT 30

except that this doesn't work and produces

[image]

Comment: I want to sort by timestamp desc but keep an event at the top of the results if it is happening within two weeks

Comment: Let me try to clarify. You want to sort the events by timestamp in descending order with the exception that those events that occur at least two times within a week have to be placed at the top. Is this correct?

Comment: not quite - if the event date is within two weeks, I want it to remain visible and stay at the top of the results (take priority over the latest timestamp)

Comment: I already did - 'events.eventdate_us' is the actual date of the event in YYYY-MM-DD - timestamp is the time it was posted. How do I write my query to order by timestamp but push the event to the top if the event date is within two weeks

Comment: ORDER BY timestamp < NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY (DESC)

Comment: It is still not clear what "within two weeks" means. Which two weeks? Latest two weeks? Any two weeks within which an event occured multiple times?

Comment: The timestamp is the time the event was posted onto the timeline. The event has a date in the future in this format YYYY-MM-DD. When a user looks at the timeline - from that point in time, if the event is going to happen within the next two weeks - I want it to be at the top of the timeline

Comment: The event date in my query is events.eventdate_us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is what I was looking for, it pins any events to the top of the results where the event date is within the next two weeks.

```
ORDER BY eventdate_us BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) DESC, 
timestamp DESC LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something more like this

```
ORDER BY eventdate_us = (eventdate_us >= (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY))) ASC, 
timestamp DESC LIMIT 30");
```

Although this isn't quite right as its still selecting a date not within two weeks (ie a future date beyond two weeks.)

Comment: Your comment above contradicts this statement "How do I write my query to order by timestamp but push the event to the top if the event date is within two weeks?" Jeff. You have to make up your mind what you want.

Comment: maybe I am over complicating this > I am trying to push an event to the top of my results like the following - ORDER BY eventdate_us = '2014-07-31' DESC, timestamp DESC LIMIT 30 but instead of the exact date, I want to get everything within two weeks to the top

Comment: And what's wrong with ORDER BY eventdate_us < NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY (DESC)

Comment: It doesn't produce the required result, the event isn't at the top

Comment: Can you prove this in an sqlfidle?

Comment: never used it so have put up some pics to illustrate what I mean

Comment: I have never used it - the query is close just not quite right

Comment: I cannot help further. Good luck.